# Laravel 5.2 validation on joined table

Tags: validation, laravel, laravel-5

I want to make validation on a joined table,I know that laravel 5.2 doesn't support this. what is the best practice to do that ? 
any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this, manually authenticate the user with the values you've grabbed from your joined database.
The fastest solution I've brought up is like this:

```
//join the tables and name it as $joined_table_values
if(isset($joined_table_values)){
   if($joined_table_values->field == 'theValueYouNeed'){
      //Then authenticate manually with the values in default users table
      if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])) {
         // Authentication passed...
         return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
      }
   }
}
```

Resource: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication#authenticating-users